# D3 csv return rows

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

This is from `d3` csv API document:

```
d3.csv("path/to/file.csv")
    .row(function(d) { return {key: d.key, value: +d.value}; })
    .get(function(error, rows) { console.log(rows); });
```

How can I pass the `rows` to a `var data` while not just `console.log` it. I just want the data from csv but I am not familiar with JavaScript.

Comment: You mean you want to save the rows to a `data` array?

Comment: Please have a look at the picture https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/1198913/655940/70e54216-d51f-11e2-84bf-4aaa7538f161.png, the `data` is over there.

Answer (score 20):

**The answer here only applies to d3 v4 and below. Starting with d3 v5, this method has changed. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599691/how-to-load-data-from-a-csv-file-in-d3-v5) for the latest solution.**

Keep in mind that it's impossible to have `d3.csv()` return any data, because the data has to first load. That's why we use callback functions, which get invoked once the data is loaded (you can learn more by researching about "asynchronous javascript").

You still can assign your loaded data to a variable, but you have to keep in mind the implication asynchronous functions.

```
// This will be assigned to rows, once the data is ready.
var myData = null;

d3.csv("path/to/file.csv")
    .row(function(d) { return {key: d.key, value: +d.value}; })
    .get(function(error, rows) {
      console.log(rows);
      myData = rows;// Now you can assign it
      myDataIsReady()// Now you can draw it
    });

// IMPORTANT NOTE! Here myData is still null
console.log(myData);// will trace null

function myDataIsReady() {
  console.log(myData);// will trace the data that was loaded
  // Here you can draw your visualization
}
```

The point is that you can't draw anything until your CSV is loaded and parsed. So no matter what, your drawing code has to live inside some function that gets called from the `d3.csv` callback.

It's possible to structure your code such that you'd never need to assign `rows` to a variable (you'd just pass `rows` into the function that draws the data).

Comment: Note that this method is changed for d3 v5, see this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599691/how-to-load-data-from-a-csv-file-in-d3-v5