# How to fetch a CSV file data one by onein order to plot a dynamic graph (D3js)

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, transition

I'm using D3js. How to fetch a CSV file data one by one (initially 10 values and then 1 value at a time)so that I can make my graph look like an animated line graph.

My CSV looks like this:

```
agraph
2
2
2
2
4
4
5
1
0
9
7
21
4
```

I found this similar question :[a link] [D3 csv return rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114826/d3-csv-return-rows).

It fetched the entire data from the file and I was able to generate a static graph.

But I want my graph to work like this(here random values have been used to generate the graph): [a link] http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/YruDh/ (found this fiddle in one of the stackoverflow questions).

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I would suggest loading the entire data at once and then passing it to D3 bit by bit, as in the example you've linked to.

Comment: I tried your suggestion for multiline dynamic graph, but still have some problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703622/multiline-dynamic-graph-d3js-data-from-a-csv-file